# selectedIndex selector (check if array of selects have selectedIndex > 0)

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-selectors, selectedindex

Instead of writing a temporary boolean, an `$.each()` on an array of `<select>` elements, and find if one's `prop('selectedIndex') > 0`, I'd like to do something like:

```
$('select[id^="idPrefixForTheArrayOfSelects-"][selectedIndex="0"]').length == 0
```

but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to select by value, selectedIndex, etc?

Comment: `selectedIndex` is a property not an attribute on select. What you have is a attribute selector. Read more http://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/297641

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this -

```
$('select[id^="idPrefixForTheArrayOfSelects-"]').filter(function(){
 return this.selectedIndex === 0;
}).length == 0
```

Comment: beautiful!  used the same thing for my textbox/textarea arrays with `$(this).val()`.  ty!